# Java Derby: How to access database reocrd by record

Tags: java, derby

I've a data with more than 20000000 rows. I want to to convert a column (which stores a number as string) to decimal format so that search can faster.

However, if I attempt via Java, by loading the data into a resultset, either the resultset crashes or java heap memory error is displayed.

Is there any way to modify each record so that the string value can be converted and saved as a decimal value in a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take Java out of the equation -- raw SQL can do this. Best approach is to add a new column, set the new column to a decimal-converted value of the existing string column, then (if you wish) drop the old string column and rename the new column.

If you're using MySQL, for instance, this would look something like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD COLUMN newcolumn DECIMAL(10,2);

UPDATE mytable
   SET newcolumn = CAST(oldcolumn AS DECIMAL(10,2))
 WHERE true;

ALTER TABLE mytable
 DROP COLUMN oldcolumn,
 CHANGE newcolumn oldcolumn DECIMAL(10,2);
```

Comment: In Derby, that final statement is two statements: one to drop the column, one to rename the newcolumn as the oldcolumn. But except for the slight syntax differences, this approach works great in Derby, too!